# My application not run when I add a maven dependency

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven module and a simple main class as following:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("HELLO");
}
```

when I run above main method , `HELLO` printed on console but when I add a dependency to my maven pom as following:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>helper</artifactId>
        <version>11.7.1.12-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

and I run main method , output of console is :

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)

where options include:
    -client   to select the "client" VM
    -server   to select the "server" VM
    -hotspot      is a synonym for the "client" VM  [deprecated]
                  The default VM is client.

    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose[:class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -jre-no-restrict-search
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  disable assertions
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                    see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
    -splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image
```

and my main method not executed.

What above happen?

**EDIT**
complete pom file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>testdevelop</groupId>
    <artifactId>testevelop</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>helper</artifactId>
            <version>11.7.1.12-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

`helper` artifact is my custom jar file.

Comment: Without the full pom file it's hard to understand what's happening.

Comment: How are you running it, on its own and with the dependency? "java Hello"? Also the full .pom file would be helpful.

Comment: Is it custom jar file?

Comment: I add pom file as complete.

Answer (score 1):

this error occurred when your pom module is invalid. I get once this error because I have a parent pom contain several pom as sub-module and I want open a sub-module only and run it without parent-module. This solved when I open main pom in idea and work fine.